# How do I insert an int into a sorted array quickly?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, copy

I'd like to insert an int into a sorted array. This operation is going to be performed very often, so it needs to be as fast as possible.

- It is possible and even preferred to use a List or any other class instead of an array
- All values are in the 1 to 34 range
- The array typically contains exactly 14 values

I was thinking of many different approaches, including binary search and simple insert-on-copy, but found it hard to decide. Also, I felt like I missed an idea. Do you have experiences on this topic or any new ideas to consider?

Comment: What sort of querying is going to be performed on the array?

Comment: @Ani mainly enumeration and some index lookup

Comment: It doesn't look too hard to code up a couple of approaches and compare their execution times.  You've had some good answers suggesting a variety of approaches, now you have to choose.  Whatcha gonna do ?

Comment: What's your application? What's usage? may be thinking in other ways for example clustering is better to improve it a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use an int array whose length is 35(because you said range 1-34) to record the status of the numbers.

```
int[] status = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 35).ToArray(); 
//an array contains 35 zeros
//which means currently there is no elements in the array
status[10] = 1;  // now the array have only one number: 10
status[11] ++;   // a new number 11 is added to the list
```

So if you want to add a number i to the list:

```
status[i]++;  // O(1) to add a number
```

To remove an i from the list:

```
status[i]--;   // O(1) to remove a number
```

Want to know all the numebrs in the list?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < status.Length; i++)
    {
        if (status[i] > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < status[i]; j++)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    //or more easier using LINQ
    var result = status.SelectMany((i, index) => Enumerable.Repeat(index, i));
```

The following example may help you understand my code better:

```
the real number array: 1 12 12 15 9 34 // i don't care if it's sorted
the status array: status[1]=1,status[12]=2,status[15]=1,status[9]=1,status[34]=1
                  all others are 0
```

Comment: While not a direct answer to my question, I consider this a very good idea since I need a histogram anyway.

Answer (score 2):

At 14 values this is a pretty small array, I don't think switching to a smarter data structure such as a list will win you much, especially if you fast good random access. Even binary search may actually be slower than linear search at this scale. Are you sure that, say, insert-on-copy does not satisfy your performance requirements?

Comment: I'm not sure :) every few ticks saved here directly translate into minutes in my case, so I was wondering if there is something better.

Comment: Well, if every tick is worth minutes, that means the entire job takes hours or days. Minor gains don't look that appealing in comparison then.

Answer (score 1):

> This operation is going to be performed very often, so it needs to be as fast as possible.

The things that you notice happen "very often" are frequently *not* the bottlenecks in the program - it's often surprising what the actual bottlenecks are. You should code something simple and measure the actual performance of your program before performing any optimizations.

> I was thinking of many different approaches, including binary search and simple insert-on-copy, but found it hard to decide.

Assuming that this is the bottleneck, the big-O performance of the different methods is not going to be relevant here because of the small size of your array. It is easier to just try a few different approaches, measure the results, see which performs best and choose that method. If you have followed the advice from the first paragraph you already have a profiler setup that you can use for this step too.

Comment: (Yes, I did, this part of the program draws 35% of the time according to the profiler.)

Comment: Have you tried implementing this functionality in unmanaged code?

Comment: @mafutct: 35% isn't a huge amount. Even if you reduced the time for this part of the program to zero (an unrealistic ideal) your program overall would still be quite slow - not even twice as fast. Perhaps you need to find a completely new approach instead of micro-optimizing this one part of your program? Do you need to store the entire list in sorted order or would a priority queue work for you?

Comment: @Gin: No, I would prefer to avoid that if possible, even though I also sense that it may be needed in the long run.

Comment: @Mark: Actually I believe 35% is a huge amount - reducing this to, say, 10% would noticeably increase performance. Of course I am also working on the other 65%.

Comment: @mafutrct: Have you considered running it on a computer that is twice as fast? Are you fully utilizing all the cores in your machine?

Answer (score 1):

For inserting into the middle, a `LinkedList<int>` would be the fastest option - anything else involves copying data. At 14 elements, don't stress over binary search etc - just walk forwards to the item you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        LinkedList<int> data = new LinkedList<int>();
        Random rand = new Random(12345);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            data.InsertSortedValue(rand.Next(300));
        }
        foreach (int i in data) Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
static class LinkedListExtensions {
    public static void InsertSortedValue(this LinkedList<int> list, int value)
    {
        LinkedListNode<int> node = list.First, next;
        if (node == null || node.Value > value)
        {
            list.AddFirst(value);
        }
        else
        { 
            while ((next = node.Next) != null && next.Value < value)
                node = next;
            list.AddAfter(node, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for O(1) when you want insert item, and If you write a simple binary search it will get a better answer.

Comment: I thought following pointers (including uncached lookups and page faults) yield worse performance in comparison with array copying? Do you have other experience?

Comment: @mafutrct - array copying isn't free. To know for sure you would have to profile for your specific scenario, I would not *expect* walking a few references to be a killer here. If you want the **absolute** performance, hard code to `LinkedList<int>` and use `<` / `>` operators instead of `Comparer<T>.Default`

Comment: @Saeed - it it pretty hard to do binary search on a linked list since you don't have indexer-based access.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the brute-force approach is the best decision here because 14 isn't a number :). However, this is not a scalable decision, since should 14 become 14000 one day that will cause problems

Comment: (14 is a real world constant in my case so it can be assumed that it always stays in the low 2 digit range.)

Comment: @mafutrct: Then brute force is the bst approac

Answer (score 0):

What is the most common operation with your array?
Insert? Read?

- Heap data structure will give you O(log(14)) for both of them. SortedDictionary may hit your performance.
- Using a simple array will give you O(1) for reading and O(14) for insert.

By the way, have you tried System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary ot System.Collections.Generic.SortedList?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .Net 4 you should take a look at the [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx). Otherwise take a look at [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) where you make `TValue` as `object` and just put `null` into it, cause you're just interested into the keys.

Comment: SortedSet does not allow dupes I think.

Comment: Yes, if you add a value a second time, the information about an element exists multiple times is lost. But in your requirements you didn't talk about duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no repeated value on the array and the possible values won´t change maybe a fixed size array where the value is equal to the index is a good choice

Both insert and read are O(1)

Comment: Correct. That's what I want to say in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a range of possible values from 1-34 which is rather narrow. So the fastest way would likely be using an array with 34 slots. To insert a number n just do array[n-1]++ and to remove it do array[n.1]-- (if n>0).

To check if a value exists in your collection you do array[n-1]>0.

*edit*: Damn...Danny was faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a method takes an array of integers and sorts them in place using Bubble Sort. The method is not allowed to create any additional arrays. Bubble Sort is a simple sorting algorithm that works by looping through the array to be sorted, comparing each pair of adjacent elements and swapping them if they are in the wrong order.